# OpenJDK 11 can't run Java 11 JARs

Tags: ubuntu, java

I have been trying to figure out why my OpenJDK 11 installation can't run JAR files compiled at class level 55. I even went so far as to completely remove Java from my system and reinstall. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Here are my steps for installing OpenJDK 11:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk-headless`

Once installed, my version shows the following:

`ryan@aurelius:~$ java -version
openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.18.04.4, mixed mode)`

And if I try to run a JAR file compiled with the same Java version, I get this:

`ryan@aurelius:~/jade$ java -jar jade-launcher-jar-with-dependencies.jar -i
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.vicinityconcepts.jade.launcher.JadeOrbitBootstrap
    java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/vicinityconcepts/jade/launcher/JadeOrbitBootstrap has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 54.0`

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION**

As stated in the comments, seems to be an issue with the OpenJDK packages in Ubuntu 18.04. After upgrading to 18.10, the package contains the correct JDK version.

Comment: This looks like a serious packaging error. That's Java 10, not Java 11. Ubuntu 18.10 actually has Java 11 in its openjdk-11 packages. But 18.04 LTS has packages _named_ openjdk-11 etc., but they actually contain Java 10.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you, that was it. I upgraded to 18.10 and I received the correct JDK now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, seems to be an issue with the OpenJDK packages in Ubuntu 18.04. After upgrading to 18.10, the package contains the correct JDK version.